# What LEGO set are these decorated tiles from?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I have a box of LEGO from when my husband was younger and I have been going through and putting them in their sets for my son. I have now run out of the instruction books and still have some sets left.

Can anyone identify what set these pieces pictures may have come from? It seems like his sets are all from the 90’s.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow nostalgia kicked in. I had this when I was a kid

Comment: I still have some Spyrius sets. Not complete, but the printed parts are all there.

Answer (score 25):

These came [from a number of sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3039pb002&in=S), including a handy ["Decorated Elements"](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=5121-1) set that covered most of the printed parts from the mid-90s space theme.

However, [Recon Robot](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=6889-1) appears to be the only one that contains two of the 2x2 tiles and only one of the 2x1 tiles.

Instructions can be found in a number of places, including on [Let's Build It Again](http://letsbuilditagain.com/instructions/6889/).

Comment: Those old-school sets made my young me drool looking at those product catalogs that came with the Lego sets back them. Recon Robot was on my wishlist until a couple months ago, when I managed to buy it used in a garage sale. It is a very nice set overall with lots of fun parts to play with, and it was part of the "Spyrius" collection.